# how to send a message that the number of Character php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

the principle is that the php script verifies if the two passwords are the same , then it counts the number of character and then returns a message that the number .i'm sorry for my English I 'm French 
My html code

```
<fieldset class="appel">
        <input id="premier_champ_password" type="password" />
        <input id="second_champ_password" type="password" />
        <input type="button" id="bouton_secrets" value="Vérifier les mots de passe"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <fieldset class="retour">
            <legend>Contenu du fichier</legend>
            <div id="retour_secrets"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>

var bouton6=document.getElementById('bouton_secrets');
bouton5.addEventListener('click', appel_contenue_secret);
```

My ajax code

```
function appel_contenue_secret(){

        var cM = new XMLHttpRequest();
            cM.open("POST","fichiers/secrets.php",true);
            cM.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var passeword = document.getElementById('premier_champ_password').value;
        var verif_passeword = document.getElementById('second_champ_password').value;
        var retour_solutions = document.getElementById('retour_solutions');
            cM.send("passeword1"+passeword&"passeword2"+verif_passeword);
            cM.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (cM.readyState == 4 && cM.status == 200)

        {
            retour_solutions.innerHTML=cM.responseText;
        }
        }
    }
```

My PHP code

i want that the script : chek if the passeword are the same 
count the number of characters in the password
return a message informing the difficulty of password according to the following principle in the output : id = retour_secret
Between 1 and 6 characters : "Mot de passe faible"
7 to 12 characters :"Mot de passe moyen"
From 13 characters : "Mot de passe complexe"

```
<?php 
$passeword = trim($_POST["passeword1"]);
$verif_passeword =trim($_POST["passeword2"]);
if ($passeword==$verif_passeword)
{$nbre = strlen($passeword);
if (1 < $nbre < 7) echo "Mot de passe faible";
else if (7 < $nbre < 12) echo "Mot de passe moyen";
else if ($nbre > 12) echo "Mot de passe complexe";}?>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work about what you have tried?

Comment: yes i tried it and when i click, its doesn't word

Comment: @sidi again .. what doesnt work ? you get any errors ? did you check the console

Comment: it doesn't gave mi any error @meda

Comment: @sidi [`See this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690052/how-to-send-a-message-that-the-number-of-character-php-ajax#comment41977383_26690199)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i saw it but i can't use those things because its an exercice and i must find a solution without frameworks :)

Comment: @sidi What do you mean without frameworks? The answer below isn't a framework, it's the solution to your existing code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'm sorry i didn' understood ;) thanks you

Comment: @sidi Tu es bienvenu mon cher ami. Et oui, je parle francais ;) Ssshhh lol

Comment: serieusement ? tu parles français @Fred-ii- or you used google translate like me haha :)

Comment: @sidi Serieux, oui. Et non pas de Google du tout. Je parle tres bien francais, l'anglais et l'italien.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ajoute moi sur skype pour que je puisse bien t'expliquer mon probeleme si tu en a

Comment: Désolé, je n'ai pas Skype. Mais pour garder ceci en anglais avant que Stack nous "flag", I can't see why the answer below isn't working for you. Which browser are you using? I am using the latest FF. @sidi

Comment: pas de problme, 'i'm using FF too and in don't know why

Comment: @sidi Did you copy the codes exactly as shown and not modify your existing code? Is there any other code that you're not showing, and you did upload the new files, and cleared your cache? He did do a slight edit to the answer also.

Comment: sorryyyy the probleme was in my button code var bouton6=document.getElementById('bouton_secrets');
    bouton5.addEventListener('click', appel_contenue_secret);  i forget to change bouton5 to bouton6 in the second sentence, thanks you @Fred-ii-

Comment: @sidi Si tu veux me rejoindre, visite mon profil et tu verras mon lien Internet. Mais, les courriels Hotmail ne fonctionnent pas (je sais pas pourquoi, Hotmail les rejete; email pour verification), au cas tu planifie te servir d'un adresse Hotmail. Au revoir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Ajax Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script>

function appel_contenue_secret(){

   var cM = new XMLHttpRequest();
        cM.open("POST","secrets.php",true);
        cM.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var passeword = document.getElementById('premier_champ_password').value;
    var verif_passeword = document.getElementById('second_champ_password').value;
    var retour_solutions = document.getElementById('retour_solutions');
        cM.send("passeword1="+passeword+"&passeword2="+verif_passeword);
        cM.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (cM.readyState == 4 && cM.status == 200)
        {
            retour_solutions.innerHTML=cM.responseText;
        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<fieldset class="appel">
    <input id="premier_champ_password" type="password" />
    <input id="second_champ_password" type="password" />
    <input type="button" id="bouton_secrets" value="Vérifier les mots de passe" onClick="appel_contenue_secret();"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <fieldset class="retour">
        <legend>Contenu du fichier</legend>
        <div id="retour_secrets"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <span id="retour_solutions"></span>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

$passeword = trim($_POST["passeword1"]);
$verif_passeword =trim($_POST["passeword2"]);
if ($passeword==$verif_passeword)
{
$nbre = strlen($passeword);

if ($nbre>=1 &&  $nbre<=7) echo "Mot de passe faible";
else if ($nbre>7 && $nbre<=12) echo "Mot de passe moyen";
else if ($nbre > 12) echo "Mot de passe complexe";

}
else
{
 echo "Passowrds didn't match!";
} 

?>
```

Note : I recommend you to use JavaScript library `jQuery` to take advantage of built-in ajax functionalities than writing lengthy JavaScript Native Code.

Comment: Did you copy all codes correctly? I got the output.

Comment: Your answer works, however, the reason why the OP's (probably) not getting any output for certain instances, is that if the entered password is 7 characters long, it won't show anything, therefore the `<` and `>` need to be `<=` and `>=` except for the last one.

Comment: @sidi Yes I changed. There was error in your PHP code.

Comment: @JensonMJohn Come to think of it, `else if ($nbre>=7 && $nbre<=12) echo "Mot de passe moyen";` the `>=7` should be `>7` since the other one `<=7` check if it's equal or less than 7, while it should be looking if it's more than 7. But, both will work, it's not a big problem and it won't break the code/functionality.

Comment: @JensonMJohn thanks you i tried  it still no output, i think maybe there is an error in my ajax function

Comment: @sidi If you copy all HTML, JavaScript & PHP Codes correctly, It shoudl work. I've tested.

Comment: @JensonMJohn do you have a skype id or something like that i want to show you my files

Comment: @JensonMJohn its work the probleme was in my button code i forget to change bouton5 to bouton6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what isn't working for your code, as you haven't specified the problem you are having, but two general practice considerations for you:

1. Use a PHP Framework. I would highly recommend Laravel. It's powerful and has an easy learning curve. It has built-in password confirmation validations for forms. http://www.laravel.com
2. I would suggest using jQuery for sending Ajax requests. The syntax is easy to learn and it makes the process dead simple. http://www.jquery.com

Using these two things will considerably decrease bugs for your code since they do a lot of the work for you.